# NAPALM library not been imported when using PyInstaller

Tags: python, import, pip, pyinstaller

I have successfully used Pyinstaller for a while and never faced issue with a library which was installed using pip. However recently i created a program using NAPALM library which is running perfectly fine from the IDE but when exported using Pyinstaller it is giving an error.

ERROR: `Cannot import "ios". Is the library installed?`

Python version: `Python 3.7.1rc2`

PIP package list:

```
C:\Users\yasir.zamir>pip list
Package         Version
--------------- ----------
napalm          2.5.0
PyInstaller     3.5
cffi            1.13.2
PyYAML          5.2
paramiko        2.6.0
textfsm         1.1.0
Jinja2          2.10.3
netaddr         0.7.19
pyeapi          0.8.2
netmiko         2.4.2
junos-eznc      2.2.1
ciscoconfparse  1.4.11
scp             0.13.2
lxml            4.4.2
setuptools      39.0.1
```

Sample Code:

```
def main():
    print("hello")
    driver = get_network_driver('ios')
    device = driver('192.168.1.1', 'admin', 'admin')
    device.open()
    device_fact=device.get_facts()
    print(device_fact['vendor'])
    print(device_fact['os_version'])
    print(device_fact['serial_number'])
    print(device_fact['model'])
    print(device_fact['hostname'])
    output_list = device_fact['os_version'].split(",")
    ios_image = output_list[0].strip()
    ios_version = output_list[1].strip()
    print(ios_image)
    print(ios_version)
```

Lastly, i have tried uninstalling and reinstalling both libraries using pip, tried in different sequence but to no avail.

Comment: Your `pip list` shows too few libraries. NAPALM [requires](https://github.com/napalm-automation/napalm/blob/develop/requirements.txt) much more. I think you need to configure PyInstaller to install them.

Comment: Thank you for correction,i have updated the full list.

Comment: @yasirzamir did you resolve this problem?